# Total the sum in Row in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Anybody have an idea how to total the sum in MS Access Table in Row. Let say I have a table TblAccount with the following field name Total. I need to sum all rows in Total field name.

Comment: What are you trying to create, a query?  Or an automatically filled new field in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a "totals" query:

```
SELECT sum(TblAccount.Total) as sumOfTotal 
FROM TblAccount;
```

This will sum the Totals fields in all your table's rows.